# Netsuite - How to get Inventory Adjustment worksheet records using a restlet

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to get a record of an Inventory Adjustment worksheet and getting the error:

```
{'error': {'code': 'INVALID_TRANS_TYP',
  'message': '{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_TRANS_TYP","message":"Transaction type specified is incorrect.
```

My code is below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([
    'N/record',
], function(record) {
    function getInv(data){
    var recordObj = record.load({
        type: "inventoryadjustment",
        id: data.rec,
        isDynamic: true
    });

        return recordObj;
    }
    return {get:getInv};
});
```

When I go to Transactions>Inventory>Adjust Worksheet>List I can see the list of all inventory adjustments with their ids. The url shows transaction type as `Transaction_TYPE=InvWksht`,not sure what that should be in script. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. I simply had to change the `type` to `inventoryworksheet`

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([
    'N/record',
], function(record) {
    function getInv(data){
    var recordObj = record.load({
        type: "inventoryworksheet",
        id: data.rec,
        isDynamic: true
    });

        return recordObj;
    }
    return {get:getInv};
});
```

Comment: i thought "inventoryworksheet" record is non-scriptable

Comment: @4N335 I’m not able to find it in the record browser but yes this particular script definitely works to this day as it was for a company app.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would prepare a CSV and import it. Note that an inventory adjustment worksheet sets inventory levels and valuation to fixed values at a given point in time with the transactional effect being whatever changes are required to do that. It is not something you would do often.

Inventory Adjustments and Inventory Counts are the common method to adjust inventory levels but only allow you to set costs for the adjusted qty.

- Worksheet: as of start of day 6 Jan 2021 make it so we have 200
  Widgets worth $5000 total.
- Adjustment: add 25 widgets at $25 each to the current 175. We end up with 200 widgets worth $5000 total.
- Inventory count: supposed to be 25 in BIN XXXAAA but there are 50. Effect is
  to adjust in 25 at the current average cost. We end up with 200 worth $5000 total.

Far as I know Inventory Worksheets are not scriptable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detail.

Comment: Oh finally I was able to read an adjustment worksheet record, I just has the wrong `type` field. But I believe your answer was more about doing actual adjustments, which I haven't ben able to do also